# Remapping Shibboleth elements at the SP end

Tags: shibboleth

We have a service that requires uid, but for reasons I can't fathom, our IDP intermittently quits sending it causing service disruptions.

However, they send mail reliably in the form uid@instution.edu

I mapped mail onto uid, but I need to strip @institution.edu from uid for the app to work properly. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Transform` type of `<AttributeResolver>`. Here is an example from the ["TransformAttributeResolver" page of the official documentation](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SP3/TransformAttributeResolver) that splits apart an attribute into two new attributes:

```
<AttributeResolver type="Transform" source="displayName">
    <Regex match="^(.+) (.+)$" dest="givenName">$1</Regex>
    <Regex match="^(.+) (.+)$" dest="sn">$2</Regex>
    <Regex match="^(.+) (.+)$">$2, $1</Regex>
</AttributeResolver>
```

This would go in `shibboleth2.xml`. In your case you could use something like

```
<AttributeResolver type="Transform" source="mail">
    <Regex match="^(.+)@mydomain.com$" dest="uidunscoped">$1</Regex>
</AttributeResolver>
```